# Prime Factorization in Ruby using Trial Division

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. I do have some past experience using python, but recently when I got back into coding I chose to learn Ruby. I am working on a program that needs to find the prime factors of a number so I created a method using trial division. Then when I try to call the method I get an error `` trial_division': undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``.

I have tried using break for the while loops instead of end and got the same results. I don't know what in ruby is causing this method to not be recognized.

```
def trial_division(n)
  a = []
  while n % 2 == 0
    a.push(2)
    n /= 2
  f = 3
  end
  while f * f < n
      if n % f == 0
        a.push(f)
        n /= f
      else
        f += 2
      end
  end
  if n != 1
    a.push(n)
  end
puts a
end
```

I'd like the program to find the prime factors of a number and display the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes as far as I can see: the `f=3` line is in the while loop, causing f to be nil when n happens to be odd. nil has no `*` method, which causes the error.

Also `while f*f<n` fails for 9, ; should be `while f*f <= n`. Note that `puts` returns `nil`, so the whole method returns nil.

Also: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division .(`require "prime"; p 100.prime_division`)